# passing chained scopes as params on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have this on my view:

```
<%= link_to "shirts", things_path (:scope => "shirts" ) %>
```

this on my controller

```
@products = Product.send(params[:scope])
```

however i would like to use chained scopes such as:

```
<%= link_to "shirts", products_path (:scope => "shirts.blue" )  %>
```

but for some reason that doesnt work.

Probably my syntax is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "shirts", products_path (:scope => "shirts.blue" ) %>
```

Model

```
@products = Product.scoped
params[:scope].split(".").each{|scope| @products = @products.send(scope)}
```

Comment: This introduces serious vulnerability - what if I user added `delete_all` as 'scope' param? Please refer to answer by BitOfUniverse and validate user input.

Answer (score 7):

If you gonna use `params` as argument for `send` method, don't forget to check it by the whitelist of scopes:

```
safe_scopes = %w(shirts pants boots blue red yellow)
```

and then you can go with `fl00r`'s soulution:

```
@products = Product.scoped
params[:scope].split(".").each{|scope| @products = @products.send(scope) if safe_scopes.include?(scope)}
```

because someone will try to send `?scope=shirts.destroy_all` to your controller or smth else.

Comment: +1 for validation. But I would rewrite your chain: `params[:scope].split(".").select{|s| safe_scope.include? s}.each{|scope| @products = @products.send(scope) }`

Comment: `(params[:scope].split('.') & safe_scopes).each{|scope| @products = @products.send(scope) }` shorter way